# Do http requests only from my app

Tags: php, android, http, request

I have an application where I make POST http requests to a server to get data. 
Now anyone can use my APIs to get data if they know the parameters to send. 
**How can I send requests only from my application?** 
When a user logs in, a firebase token is generated that is unique to each device. Can I use this token?

Thanks guys

Comment: Firebase token is unique but can be difficult to maintain so i prefer using a key which should be unique can be used while calling your api. Then your api should respond to those valid api key only.

Comment: How do I generate this unique key? Then on the server should I store this unique key?

Comment: This unique can be any hash key etc. Yes you should store in server.

Comment: can i use the private key of the app?

Comment: any key can be used.